# Casual way of saying "send me an email"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, email

Is there a more casual way to say "send me an email"?

I'm going to put this at the bottom of the "contact" section of a website.

"Pop me an email" is the only one I've managed to come up with.

Comment: "mail me" -- no caps, no punctuation, either.

Comment: *Send (me)* is one the simplest, easiest and flexible requests. It also fits in with more formal sentences such as: *Would you mind sending me an e-mail?* and in *Send an email asap*. Are you looking for a slang expression?

Comment: @Mari-LouA No, not necessarily slang, just something to leave at the bottom of the "contact" section of a site.

Comment: Drop me a line.

Comment: Could you edit your question and include your previous comment, it provides more context. Thanks.

Comment: 'Fire me an email'

Comment: *Send mail.*  No “an”. No “e—”.

Comment: @AE Thanks, I've decided on using "Drop me a line."

Comment: Surprised nobody's mentioned what is to me the most obvious: _shoot me an email/a message_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Email me**

In the same vein as

- text me
- call me
- ping me

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for street slang, "Holla!", "Hit me up", or "ping me" are a few options. For a trifle less colloquial element, "drop me a note/line" is apt. Source: http://onlineslangdictionary.com/thesaurus/words+meaning+to+contact,+call,+mail.html